# Polymer reflect functions across elements

Tags: polymer

1. I have a behavior that is shared across elements.
2. In a element i have a on-change="_toggle" switch.
3. In a second element i have the same code from the first element without the switch button. when the switch is active it reflect to the element containing the switch.

Q: how can i reflect the on-change="_toggle" function across all elements?

my code:

1.

```
<script>
  LanguageBehavior = {

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior
    ],

    properties: {
      language: {
        value: 'sl',
        reflectToAttribute: true
      },
    },

    attached: function() {
      this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('/data/locales.json'));
    },

    _toggle: function() {
      this.language = this.$.switch.checked ? 'en' : 'sl';
      // This function is the problem?
    }

  };
</script>
```

2

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="behavior.html">

<dom-module id="bazdara-element-1">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
     }
   </style>
      {{localize('menu_2')}}  // THIS CHANGES WITH THE SWITCH
      <span title="english"> SI</span>
      <paper-toggle-button on-change="_toggle" id="switch"></paper-toggle-button>
      <span title="french">EN</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'bazdara-element-1',
      behaviors: [Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior, LanguageBehavior],
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

3

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="behavior.html">

<dom-module id="bazdara-element-2">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
     }
   </style>
      {{localize('menu_2')}}  // THIS Doesnt change
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'bazdara-element-2',
      behaviors: [Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior, LanguageBehavior],
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each element will have its own copy of the behavior your approach is not going to work. Right now the only options i can come up with is:

1. keep both your elements in one common element and change the property there.
2. If you are planning to have all your elements in one single html file you can then change this feature in that html file and bind the property to all your elements.

Comment: On further search i found that `paper-toast` does not allow more than one toast to be opened at a time. It has declared a variable `currentToast` outside the polymer function and that remains same across the toasts. Maybe you can look at its code at it might help.

Comment: i have a lot more than 2 elements, i cant use just one element. i wanted to translate the whole app... btw its not paper-toast that i use its paper-toggle-button

Comment: What i was suggesting was to look at it's code and it might give you some idea on how to achieve it. Anyway's if it's localization you are trying to achieve then why don't you try `i18n-msg`. [Here's](https://ebidel.github.io/i18n-msg/components/i18n-msg/) a link for the same.

Comment: @a1626 I think you might also want to check out the polymer team's [AppLocalizeBehavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-localize-behavior)

Comment: @Alan Yes this can also do the trick, but it is still in beta version.